# How to design a parser for backward compatibility?

Tags: python, parsing

I plan to write a parser that parses input data, selects and modifies a subset of fields and output them into a different format. That's the easy part. The schema of the input data might change in future and I want my parser to be able to handle last n input schemas for backward compatibility. Hopefully, the output schema doesn't have to change but if it does, I'd like it to keep it to the minimum. My question is - how should I organize the parser code to handle such incremental change to the input schema while reusing code as much as possible. I'd also like to keep it simple for a new guy to come in and easily add support for the next version.

If it matters, the input data has records with types and sub-types (so modular parsing possible). The programming language will be python (so reflection possible). Input format is message pack and output format is json.

There are few options on my mind. Open to whatever suggestions -

1. Have completely different versions of parser and maintain a mapping of input schema to parser version. Copy paste code as needed.
2. Have a single parser with switch case on input schema version, within the code as needed.
3. Have inheritance based structure where the new version of parser inherits from the older version of parser, overrides whatever functions necessary.

Comment: This seems a matter of overall flexible software design, with the decisions made on speculations for the future ... in short, not a SO-type of question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to maintain backwards compatibility, you'll want to have clear modules and clear function. Don't have one section of code trying to do too much.

The spec shouldn't change too much, so you could just have `if-else` statements within your functions. Make sure the actual behavior of the functions doesn't evolve, though.